# Symfony2: Querying for object with 2 other objects as parameters

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm

What is the best way to do the following: I have a `gameobject` entity which has properties `game` and `user`. Now my method gets the game id and the user id and i want to look for the `gameobject` with `game` = object of game id and `user` = object of user id.

I have tried the following:

```
    $game = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("xxx:Game")->find($game_id);
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("xxx:User")->find($user_id);
    $gameobject_query = $em->getRepository('xxx:Gameobject')->createQueryBuilder('g')
        ->where('g.game = :game AND g.user = :user')
        ->setParameters(array(
            'game' => $game,
            'user' => $user
        ))
        ->getQuery();
    $gameobject = $gameobject_query->getResult();
```

Your advices would be appriciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that something like the following should work:

```
$repository = this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('xxx:GameObject');
$queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('go')
    ->innerJoin('go.game', 'g')
    ->innerJoin('go.user', 'u')
    ->where('g.id = :gameId')
    ->andWhere('u.id = :userId')
    ->setParameter('gameId', $gameId)
    ->setParameter('userId', $userId);

$gameObjects = $queryBuilder->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Alternatively, the following may also work and be more efficient: It should do the same but without needing to join to the other entities:

```
$repository = this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('xxx:GameObject');
$queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('go')
    ->where('IDENTIY(go.game) = :gameId')
    ->andWhere('IDENTITY(go.user) = :userId')
    ->setParameter('gameId', $gameId)
    ->setParameter('userId', $userId);

$gameObjects = $queryBuilder->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you use the findOneBy method of your Gameobject repo ?

```php
$game = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("xxx:Game")->find($game_id);
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("xxx:User")->find($user_id);
$gameobject = $em->getRepository('xxx:Gameobject')->findOneBy(array(
        'game' => $game,
        'user' => $user
    ));
```